# Iterate over a custom set in SAS

Tags: loops, macros, sas

First of all, apologize for my poor english but that's because I'm not native. I'm a newbie in SAS programming too, and I need someone to help me with this problem struggling me. 
I have one dataset A containing a numeric field YM representing year and month (e.g., 200902) that I'm using to filter the dataset. In particular, I want to get N filtered datasets using N differents values YM.

- A_filtered_200901 = A.filter(YM == 200901)
- A_filtered_200902 = A.filter(YM == 200902)
- A_filtered_200903 = A.filter(YM == 200903)
- ...

My idea was to generate the sequence of YM used to filter and then give it as an argument to a %macro containing a PROC SQL. In code/pseucode:

```
data ym_dataset;
    date = input(put(20090201, 8.), yymmdd8.);
    do i = 1 to 3;
        aux1 = intnx('MONTH', date, i);
        aux2 = put(aux1, yymmddn8.);
        list_of_ym_values = substr(aux2 , 1, 6);
        output;
    end;
run;

%macro my_macro(list_of_ym_values);
    proc sql;
    %do i = 1 %to dim(&list_of_ym_values)
      select * 
      from A 
      where YM = &list_of_ym_values(i)
    %end        
    quit;
%mend my_macro;

%my_macro(ym_dataset[list_of_ym_values])
```

I know that this is not the correct approach, but I hope that someone could shed me some light about doing it properly.

Thank you!!

Comment: Is there a particular reason for splitting your data ?  Being new to SAS do you know that much 'splittig' can occur logically using `where` statements, and `by` statements ?  The `by` statement will automatically process observations in *groups* when the data is sorted appropriately.

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n01vuhy8h909xgn16p0x6rddpoj9.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I could use SELECT + AGG FUNCTION + GROUP BY in order to get all groups, but actually I simplified the statement of my problem in the seek of generality,. My true problem is the following: construct a time series counting the elements of each dataset iterating over the N dates, but using two filters A.filter(INI_YM < 200901 & END_YM > 200901 ) instead the one I presented. So my approach is to construct the N datasets with the format [YM, Count] and then append all of them to get the time series dataset.

Comment: By the way, that comment is the answer to Richard :D. Reeza, thank you for the documentation, it is very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need loop through list of variables and this values can be created in a macro variable. But as @richard suggested in comments is not great idea to split datasets.

```
 /* create macrovariable with all values*/  
proc sql;
select list_of_ym_values into :List
 separated by "|" from ym_dataset;
%put &list;

/* scan through each variable and create new dataset*/
 %macro one;
 %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list),"|") ;
 %let val= %scan(&list,&i,|);
proc sql;
create table want_&val as
select * from ym_dataset
where list_of_ym_values = "&val";
%end;
 %mend;
%one;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kiran! After adapting your code to my particular case, it has worked perfectly :D